# Looping an array and storing the values to a hash in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to loop an array which might look like following:

```
names = ['sid','john'] #this array will  be dynamic, The values keep changing
```

I am trying to write a method where I will define an empty hash and loop the array using `.each`
and then store the values to hash.But not working.

```
def add_address
 names = ['sid','john']
 addr_arr = {}
 names.each do |n|
  addr_arr['name'] = n
 end
addr_arr
end
```

this returns only `{"name"=>"john"}`.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your implementation is that there's only one hash and each time you set a value for the `"name"` key, the previous value for that key will be deleted and replaced by the new value.

I see `addr_arr` has `arr` in the name, so I assume you wanted something like this:

```
def add_address
 names = ['sid','john']
 addr_arr = []
 names.each do |n|
  addr_arr << { "name" => n}
 end
addr_arr
end

add_address
#=> [{"name"=>"sid"}, {"name"=>"john"}]
```

or shorter:

```
['sid','john'].map{ |name| {"name" => name} }
#=> [{"name"=>"sid"}, {"name"=>"john"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you always use the key `'name'`, you're overwriting its values every time, I don't think that's what you want. I don't know if this is what you want anyway, but this should be enough to understand the problem

```
names.each do |n|
  addr_arr[n] = n
end
```